# Spectrum of bounded self adjoint operator

Tags: self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be bounded self adjoint operator. Then, at least one or both of $\|A\|$, $-\|A\|$ is in spectrum $\sigma(A)$. I can not prove this.

I'd appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: This is fairly clear from the Spectral Theorem. Maybe that counts as too easy and we want a solution from first principles...

Comment: Thanks! I find the theorem, a necessary and sufficient condition for that self adjoint operator $T$ is bounded is spectral family $E(\lambda)$ is bounded, and then $\|T\|=\max\{|\min E|, |\max E|\}$.